# GIMP get current image reference number to operate on current image

Tags: script-fu

I have more than one image open, and I'd like to run scrip-fu functions on the currently selected image. How can I get the image reference number to the currently selected image so I can use the reference in other functions (e.g. `(gimp-image-width 7)`)? I'm using GIMP 2.10.12.

Using `(gimp-image-list)` lists all the image references:

```
> (gimp-image-list)
(12 #(12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using (gimp-image-latest) for this, which should work for the general case

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(define (gimp-image-list-items)
  (cadr (gimp-image-list)))

(define (gimp-image-latest)
  (aref (gimp-image-list-items) 0))

(define img (gimp-image-latest))
```

Then it's in `img`. E.g.:

```lisp
> (gimp-image-get-layers img)
(283 #(770 769 768 767 766 765 764 763 762 761 760 759 758 757 756 755 754 753 752 751 750 749 748 747 746 745 744 743 742 741 740 739 738 737 736 735 734 733 732 731 730 729 728 727 726 725 724 723 722 721 720 719 718 717 716 715 714 713 712 711 710 709 708 707 706 705 704 703 702 701 700 699 698 697 696 695 694 693 692 691 690 689 688 687 686 685 684 683 682 681 680 679 678 677 676 675 674 673 672 671 670 669 668 667 666 665 664 663 662 661 660 659 658 657 656 655 654 653 652 651 650 649 648 647 646 645 644 643 642 641 640 639 638 637 636 635 634 633 632 631 630 629 628 627 626 625 624 623 622 621 620 619 618 617 616 615 614 613 612 611 610 609 608 607 606 605 604 603 602 601 600 599 598 597 596 595 594 593 592 591 590 589 588 587 586 585 584 583 582 581 580 579 578 577 576 575 574 573 572 571 570 569 568 567 566 565 564 563 562 561 560 559 558 557 556 555 554 553 552 551 550 549 548 547 546 545 544 543 542 541 540 539 538 537 536 535 534 533 532 531 530 529 528 527 526 525 524 523 522 521 520 519 518 517 516 515 514 513 512 511 510 509 508 507 506 505 504 503 502 501 500 499 498 497 496 495 494 493 492 491 490 489 488))
```

Comment: The list returned by `(gimp-image-list)` doesn't seem to be sorted by most recently used, just most recently created, so this doesn't actually return the currently selected image.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here suggest registering a script-fu script because then GIMP will pass the correct image reference number when you run it.

[How to identify the latest selected image in gimp from (scheme function) gimp-image-list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678050/how-to-identify-the-latest-selected-image-in-gimp-from-scheme-function-gimp-im)

The documentation says that GIMP will pass the active image and active layer as the first two parameters to registered scripts.
https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial-first-script.html#idm9935